# How to handle deletions or updates for records read into Azure Data Explorer?

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer

I am trying to understand how Azure Data Explorer get updates with deletion or modification of records. I see documentation to using ingestion hub but that is only for appending records. What about deleting or modifying?

Do you have to create an entire new Database with each change or batch the changes?

My goal is to create a 30TB database with 1kb records. Need to run quick queries on time ranges, owner of record, flat column values. Sometimes records need to be deleted based on TTL or explicitly by API call

Comment: Questions like this are getting closed with the following reason: "Needs more focus This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.". I narrowed the tags and I'll edit the text. If you want to get an additional answer for an additional service, please post an additional question.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Data Explorer was created with the initial purpose of handling logs in large scale.

- Logs are not getting updated, so it was designed with append only approach (insert only).
- Logs do become less relevant or completely irrelevant as time passes, so it was created with built-in retention capabilities based on [retention policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/retentionpolicy).
- At some point a [soft delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/concepts/data-soft-delete) capability was added, as well as a [purge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/concepts/data-purge) capability, to support [GDPR](https://gdpr-info.eu/) (General Data Protection Regulation).

  > "Unlike .purge, the .delete command doesn't reingest the data. It just
  > marks records that are returned by the predicate query as deleted and
  > is therefore much faster."